# How to format a textbox for date of birth

Tags: javascript, html

I've decided to use a textbox for getting the users date of birth, I'm trying to make this textbox so it restricts the users input into DD/MM/YYYY, What i'm trying to get is to that the slash(/) is fixed within the textbox. The user won't want to have the type the "/" so I'm trying to get it fixed in the textbox

This is what I'm trying to achieve

---

|____/____/___|

my code so far is just a basic textbox but here it is anyway

```
<label for="title">Date of Birth</label>
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[How to do date masking using javascript (without JQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108620/how-to-do-date-masking-using-javascript-without-jquery)

If you check the Pratik Shah answer there's the format you were looking for and it seems to work.

Code:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="date"
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onkeyup="
        var v = this.value;
        if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
        } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
            this.value = v + '/';
       }"
    maxlength="10"
>
```

It works on my Firefox 52.0.2

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is ideal since it works on all browsers, Thanks!

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when trying to backspace. What you can do for this is add `!== null && backspaceTriggered` to the end of each `if` statement. Then add an `else` which simple sets `this.value = v`

Comment: It'd be really cool if this could also ignore when the user manually types the slashes (`/`).

Answer (score 8):

With HTML5 you could simply use the date input type:

```html
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
```

Here's the MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: It seems a little finicky with the year, it's interesting

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, my only concern is that on firefox this doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure if this is on my end or just not firefox supported. Thanks anyway

Comment: Not supported in FF.

Comment: @TF120 There are plenty of polyfills available. This one looks pretty good: https://github.com/brianblakely/nodep-date-input-polyfill Using the native `date` type with a polyfill is probably the most accessible solution across devices and locales.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for.

```
<input type="date" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
```

Bear in mind that this won't work in certain browsers -- Firefox and older IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try maskedInput plugin for jQuery. It is basically what you are looking for. https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput